# Particle effect in sprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I want to create a particle effect when my player sprite collide with my star sprite. How can I add a particleSystem in the sprite and not in a image?
Also, I wish if it could wait for the animation for some miliseconds, and then remove the star sprite.

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair starCollision:
    (CCNode *)star playerCollision:(CCNode *)_player {
    NSLog(@"----------Colisao---------");

    //update score
    score += 1;
    [scorelabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];
    NSLog(@"score %d", score);


    CCParticleSystem *particleSystem = [[CCParticleSpiral alloc] initWithTotalParticles:1000];

    [self addChild:particleSystem];
    //[particleSystem release];
    //[particleSystem setTexture:[[CCTextureCache  sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"star.png"];


    //remove stars
    [star removeFromParent];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing where you are positioning the particle system, only that you are adding it to "self".  I assume you want the particle system to be more or less at the same position as the star sprite.

Assuming "self" is a layer, you need to position the particle system using the position of the star sprite, and offset the position where needed.

```
particleSystem.position = star.position;
```

Or you could just add the particle system as a child of the star sprite, and offset the position where needed.

```
[star addChild:particleSystem];
```

With regard to waiting some period of time before removing the star sprite, you could use actions to do this.  The first action would be a delay, and the second action would then call a method to remove the star:

```
id delayAction = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1];
CCAction * removeStar = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeStar)];
[star runAction:[CCSequence actions: delayAction, removeStar, nil]];

- (void) removeStar {
    [star removeFromParent];
}
```

Your question was not very clear, so this was the best I could do with the information provided.  Also, it does not appear that you are properly preparing the particle system.  But, since you did not specifically ask about that I am assuming your code just lists the basic information about this.

I hope this helps.